# Out of bounds exception multiplying arrays

Tags: java, arrays

As far as my knowledge goes, this program is done correctly. However, given the exception it appears not. I am to make 2 arrays of length x (user inputted) and the user is to input the elements. Done. Next multiply each element by its corresponding element in the other array and add the sum total.

Ex, array1[0]*array2[0] + array1[1]*array2[1]...

Precise error is : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

I have done many different loops, the last loop below that I have spaced extra to identify is what I think is closest to correct but not. I would much appreciate some advice, thank you in advance.

```
   System.out.println("This program will multiply 2 one dimension arrays of any length. \n The length and contents of the array is entered from the keyboard.");
    System.out.println("Enther the data for the first array. ");

    System.out.println("Enther the length of the array (remember arrays being counting at 0, not 1:");

    int a = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    a = keyboard.nextInt();
    int[] firstArrayLength = new int[a];
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the first array(remember arrays begin counting at 0, not 1");
    double arrayElements = 0;
    for (int elements = 0; elements <= firstArrayLength.length; elements++) {

        arrayElements = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Enter the data for the second array. ");
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the second  array(remember arrays begin counting at 0, not 1");
    int[] secondArrayLength = new int[a];

    double secondArrayElements = 0;
    for (int elements = 0; elements <= secondArrayLength.length; elements++) {

        secondArrayElements = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    double [] thirdArray = new double [a];





    for (int i =0; i <=firstArrayLength.length; i++)
       {
        thirdArray[a] = firstArrayLength[i]*secondArrayLength[i];
        }
    System.out.println(thirdArray);
        }
```

Comment: I am aware my loop does not add yet, I didn't add that to it as I thought it was not necessary just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `<=` symbols to `<` when you are accessing de array. For instance:

```
for (int elements = 0; elements < firstArrayLength.length; elements++)
...
```

Remember if the `length` is 4, you can access elements as:

```
array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3] // 4 elements
```

`array[4]` doesn't exist, that cause the `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.

**Edit**

The strange output `[I@756a7c99` (for instance) is because you are printing an array as:

```
int a[] = new int[4];
System.out.println(a);
```

Instead, you may want to print elements of that array:

```
int a[] = new int[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

**Edit 2**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out
            .println("This program will multiply 2 one dimension arrays of any length. \n The length and contents of the array is entered from the keyboard.");
    System.out.println("Enther the data for the first array. ");

    System.out
            .println("Enther the length of the array (remember arrays being counting at 0, not 1:");

    int a = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    a = keyboard.nextInt();
    int[] firstArray = new int[a];
    System.out
            .println("Enter the elements of the first array(remember arrays begin counting at 0, not 1");
    for (int elements = 0; elements < firstArray.length; elements++) {

        firstArray[elements] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Enter the data for the second array. ");
    System.out
            .println("Enter the elements of the second  array(remember arrays begin counting at 0, not 1");
    int[] secondArray = new int[a];

    for (int elements = 0; elements < secondArray.length; elements++) {

        secondArray[elements] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    double[] thirdArray = new double[a];

    for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
        thirdArray[i] = firstArray[i]*secondArray[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < thirdArray.length; i++)
        System.out.println(thirdArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Okay that helped, but now the program prints "[D@17b0b765" instead of a valid answer. What is that?

Comment: Okay I fixed that, now I get 0.0 for my answer. The decimal is because of double if I am correct, but the zero is throwing me off.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you may want to do this: `thirdArray[i] = firstArrayLength[i]*secondArrayLength[i];` and after that, print the elements. Note I changed `[a]` to `[i]`.

Comment: I actually tried that just before I read your comment, still getting the 0.0 unfortunately.

Comment: Have you printed the `firstArray` and `secondArray` elements? Are they correct?

Comment: Just did and they are in fact correct. Edit: hang on one second, I'm going to try something.

Comment: Mmmm that's strange. Are you sure all the arrays lengths are correct? I will try your code. Wait a second.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to print the arrays and only the last element is printed. If I try adding an index I get "array required but double found." interesting.

Comment: Ahh I see it now, and it works. Now what would i need to do in order to add them together? I just tried a few things and I'm getting numbers that I don't even know where they're coming from. Edit: I may have just gotten it. Edit : nevermind. It worked in only one case.

Comment: To convert an array to a string all at once, use the `Arrays.toString()` methods.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a million Christian!
I did: 
for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
sum+=thirdArray[i];

Answer (score 0):

`elements <= firstArrayLength.length` ==> `elements < firstArrayLength.length`

`arrayElements = keyboard.nextInt();` ==>> `firstArrayLength[elements] = keyboard.nextInt();`

`secondArrayElements = keyboard.nextInt();` ==>> `secondArrayLength[elements] = keyboard.nextInt();`

Comment: Currently printing 0.0 as a solution regardless of the element values. Suggestions at all?

Comment: is that the hall code because you are typing thirdarray inside the loop. you should do it out side!